# Nothing displayed from if else statement in map return

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to use if else within a map return but nothing is being returned. I don't get any error messages and the if is working because I can console.log from it. I'm not sure what the error is because the code looks fine.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

import { Consumer } from '../context'

import PollCard from './PollCard'

class Polls extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Consumer>
                {value => {
                    const { polls } = value


                    if (polls === undefined || polls.length === 0) {
                        return (<p>Polls loading</p>)

                    } else {
                        polls.map(poll => {
                            const current = poll.create_at
                            const next = poll.create_at

                            if (Date.parse(next) > Date.parse(current)) {

                                return (
                                    <div>
                                        <h1>{poll.create_at}</h1>
                                        <PollCard key={poll.id} poll={poll} />

                                    </div>

                                )

                            }
                            return (
                                <div>
                                    <h1>test</h1>
                                    <PollCard key={poll.id} poll={poll} />
                                </div>

                            )

                        })

                    }
                }}
            </Consumer>

        )
    }
}


export default Polls;
```

Comment: `next` and `current` have the same value so the `if` condition will never be true. Other than that, you run a `.map` but never do anything with the result of it - you have to `return polls.map()`

Answer (score 0):

You need to return polls.map in your else statement.

The first statement in your map function will never be true. current & next are both equal to poll.created_at so next can't be greater than current.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Consumer } from '../context';
import PollCard from './PollCard';

class Polls extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Consumer>
        {(value) => {
          const { polls } = value;

          if (polls === undefined || polls.length === 0) {
            return <p>Polls loading</p>;
          }
          return polls.map((poll) => {
            const current = poll.create_at;
            const next = poll.create_at;

            /* This will never be true - they are both equal because they both equal poll.created_at */
            if (Date.parse(next) > Date.parse(current)) {
              return (
                <div>
                  <h1>{poll.create_at}</h1>
                  <PollCard key={poll.id} poll={poll} />
                </div>
              );
            }
            return (
              <div>
                <h1>test</h1>
                <PollCard key={poll.id} poll={poll} />
              </div>
            );
          });
        }}
      </Consumer>
    );
  }
}

export default Polls;
```